# Asynchronous operation of the BatchBlock in BackgroundService

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, rabbitmq, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

I need to receive messages from a queue broker and, after some processing, store them in a database. In order to save records in blocks, i use a [BatchBlock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.batchblock-1?view=net-7.0).
All this works through the [BackgroundService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.backgroundservice?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0)

Code:

```
public class Worker : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
    private readonly BatchBlock<Comment> _batchBlock;
    private readonly ActionBlock<Comment[]> _importer;
    private readonly ConnectionFactory _factory;
    private readonly IModel _channel;
    private const string _queueName = "Comment";
    private static int count;

    public Worker(IConfiguration configuration, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;

        _factory = new ConnectionFactory
            { Uri = new Uri(configuration.GetSection("RabbitMqConnection").Value), DispatchConsumersAsync = true };
        var connection = _factory.CreateConnection();
        _channel = connection.CreateModel();
        _channel.QueueDeclare(queue: _queueName, durable: true, exclusive: false, autoDelete: false, arguments: null);
        
        _batchBlock = new BatchBlock<Comment>(50);
        _importer = new ActionBlock<Comment[]>(SaveCommentsToDb);
        _batchBlock.LinkTo(_importer, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });
    }
    
    protected override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        stoppingToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        var consumer = new AsyncEventingBasicConsumer(_channel);
        consumer.Received += async (_, ea) =>
            await StartCommentHandlerGroup(ea);

        _channel.BasicConsume(_queueName, false, consumer);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private async Task StartCommentHandlerGroup(BasicDeliverEventArgs message)
    {
        try
        {
            var content = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Body.ToArray());
            var comment = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Comment>(content);

            await _batchBlock.SendAsync(comment);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.Error($"!!!Handler error!!! {e.Message}{Environment.NewLine} !!!Message!!!{message.Body}");
            throw;
        }
    }

    private async Task SaveCommentsToDb(Comment[] comments)
    {
        using var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope();
        var dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<Context>();

        await dbContext.AddMessagesToDb(comments);
    }
}
```

It works very weird.....
If i set the BatchSize parameter to 10, about 200 records get into the database, if i set it to 2, about 300 hits. I set the [BatchSize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.batchblock-1.batchsize?view=net-7.0#system-threading-tasks-dataflow-batchblock-1-batchsize) to 50 and higher and nothing gets into the database.
In this case, the queue is consumed correctly. SendAsync works correctly in the BatchBlock, the Task returns true.
After a certain part of the processing is done, i get the [InputCount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.actionblock-1.inputcount?view=net-7.0) parameters in the _importer - 0 and the status is IsCompleted - true.

No matter how many new messages from the broker i receive in the future, this does not change the situation in any way and the ActionBlock is not called.

`await dbContext.AddMessagesToDb(comments)` contains:

```
foreach (var model in models)
    await DbContext.AddAsync(model);

await DbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

I tried adding the [BoundedCapacity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.dataflowblockoptions.boundedcapacity?view=net-7.0) parameter, but it didn't work.

```
batchBlock = new BatchBlock<Comment>(10, new GroupingDataflowBlockOptions(){BoundedCapacity = 50});
```

Comment: What is the value of the `_importer.Completion.Status` property? Most likely an error happens there, and unlike other places you are not logging it (no try/catch in the `SaveCommentsToDb`).

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Yes, there is an error. I was stupid and did not set up the EF correctly.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem Alex. In case the problem is solved, you could consider closing the question by clicking the Close link under the tags, for the reason "not reproducible, caused by a typo".

Comment: An alternative to adding try/catch inside the delegate of the `ActionBlock<T>`, could be to add an `async void` `OnErrorLog` extension method for tasks as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62233591/task-continuewith-executing-but-task-status-is-still-running/62237760#62237760), and use it like this: `_importer.Completion.OnErrorLog("Importer");`.