# Difference between FirstOrDefaultAsync().ContinueWith() and Select().FirstOfDefaultAsync()

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

What is the difference between these 2 snippets of code? As I understand the first one is going to make the database request do the transformation and the second is going to compute the transformation once the request is done?

> await _dbContext.myEntity.Select(x=> x.ToModel()).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

and

> await _dbContext.myEntity.FirstOrDefaultAsync().ContinueWith(x=> x?.Result?.ToModel())

Where .ToModel() is an extension method that transform database objects to domain objects and handle null values.

Comment: *the first one is going to make the database request do the transformation* -- So check if that actually happens. It probably doesn't because `x.ToModel()` can't be translated into SQL. Apart from that, when using `async-await` you don't need `ContinueWith`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> As I understand the first one is going to make the database request do the transformation and the second is going to compute the transformation once the request is done?

Unless you have [explained](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/user-defined-function-mapping) EF how to translate your custom method `ToModel` into SQL the only difference between the two would be that the second one uses `ContinueWith` which is discouraged ([click](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/21296#issuecomment-720099021), [click](https://github.com/davidfowl/AspNetCoreDiagnosticScenarios/blob/master/AsyncGuidance.md#prefer-await-over-continuewith)) in modern .NET in "general" case. Assuming you are using one of the later iterations of EF Core - it can handle custom function in the final projection (by fetching all the data for the `myEntity`, so it can lead to over-fetching if not all data is actually needed for `ToModel`).

Comment: Why is ContinueWith discouraged?  That is continuation passing style; I assumed it was the bees knees nowadays.

Comment: @RobertHarvey this is my understanding from the attached links, several discussions at SO (can't find those, though) and a bit confusing API ([this question for example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62233591/2501279)). Again I'm talking about "general" (not the best wording, I can agree) case, i.e. when you already have  task and you actually just need to await the results. For sure there are use cases when it is needed but I would argue that in the modern day-to-day development it is rather a code smell than a common practice.

Comment: @RobertHarvey `async`/`await` abstracts the concept of continuations for you, which is why it is fairly uncommon to see `ContinueWith` it being used directly in C# code these days.